# Integration in Calculus and integrals

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be a function continuous on $[0, 1]$ and twice differentiable on $(0, 1)$.

Suppose that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and 
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \ dx = 0$$
Prove that there exists a number $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f′′(x_0) = 0$.

What are the theorems that I use? MVT? Rolle's? I'm not very sure how to approach this question. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Let
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ so
$$F(0)=F(1)=0,F'(0)=F'(1)=0$$
since
$$F(0)=F(1)=0$$ use Roll's,there exist $\xi\in(0,1)$ such $$F'(\xi)=0$$
so
$$F'(0)=F'(\xi)=F'(1)=0$$
so there $\eta_{1}\in (0,\xi),\eta_{2}\in (\xi,1)$ such
$$F''(\eta_{1})=F''(\eta_{2})=0$$
use Roll's 
 then  exist $x_{0}\in (\eta_{1},\eta_{2})$ such
$$F'''(x_{0})=0$$
or
$$f''(x_{0})=0$$

Comment: You could have made that much simple by using the Mean Value Theorem. No need to introduce the anti-derivative.